# Algorithm K-Means

Tags: java, arrays

Friends, I hope your help, I am developing the K-Means algorithm in Java, so I have already performed for cycles to do the respective centroid operations with the Data and determine the distances, but the distances of each Centroid are in different for cycles. Now what I require is to put all those results in oneself outside the cycles. I enclose part of the code.

```
 System.out.println("\n" + "----------" + "\n" + "Cluster K" + "\n" + "----------");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < Datos.length; i++) {
            distanciaK = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Datos[i][0] - Datos[10][0], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][1] - Datos[10][1], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][2] - Datos[10][2], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][3] - Datos[10][3], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][4] - Datos[10][4], 2));
            System.out.println(distanciaK);

        }

        System.out.println("\n" + "----------" + "\n" + "Cluster M" + "\n" + "----------");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < Datos.length; i++) {
            distanciaM = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Datos[i][0] - Datos[12][0], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][1] - Datos[12][1], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][2] - Datos[12][2], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][3] - Datos[12][3], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][4] - Datos[12][4], 2));
            System.out.println(distanciaM);

        }

        System.out.println();
```

**Code Output**

### Cluster K

9.0
8.485281
9.380832
6.3245554
4.2426405
3.6055512
7.615773
8.83176
2.828427
5.8309517
0.0
4.7958317
5.477226
5.196152

---

### Cluster M

5.196152
4.8989797
9.486833
6.928203
4.8989797
3.8729835
7.071068
7.071068
3.1622777
4.2426405
5.477226
6.708204
0.0
1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
```

Import above packages
Created Map with as cluster name and value as list representing the cluster.
Adding the means to the respective map entry.

```
System.out.println("\n" + "----------" + "\n" + "Cluster K" + "\n" + "----------");
        System.out.println();
        Map<String,List<Float>> clusterMeanInfo = new HashMap<>();
        clusterMeanInfo.put("Cluster K",new ArrayList<>());
        clusterMeanInfo.put("Cluster M",new ArrayList<>());
        for (int i = 0; i < Datos.length; i++) {
            distanciaK = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Datos[i][0] - Datos[10][0], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][1] - Datos[10][1], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][2] - Datos[10][2], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][3] - Datos[10][3], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][4] - Datos[10][4], 2));
            System.out.println(distanciaK);
            clusterMeanInfo.get("Cluster K").add(distanciaK);

        }

        System.out.println("\n" + "----------" + "\n" + "Cluster M" + "\n" + "----------");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < Datos.length; i++) {
            distanciaM = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Datos[i][0] - Datos[12][0], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][1] - Datos[12][1], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][2] - Datos[12][2], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][3] - Datos[12][3], 2) + Math.pow(Datos[i][4] - Datos[12][4], 2));
            System.out.println(distanciaM);
            kMeans.add(distanciaM);
            clusterMeanInfo.get("Cluster K").add(distanciaM);
        }

        for (String key :clusterMeanInfo.keySet()) {
            System.out.print(key + ' ');
            clusterMeanInfo.get(key).forEach( value -> {
                System.out.print(value + ' ');
            });
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Hello friend, modify the code and if it came out. One asks the part of the code KMeans.add (DistanceM), the KMeans is referring to the class name?
The results come out but everything is horizontal, since I tried with a line break but it does not work, I would like to show these data in table form.

Comment: **{Cluster K=[9.0, 8.485281, 9.380832, 6.3245554, 4.2426405, 3.6055512, 7.615773, 8.83176, 2.828427, 5.8309517, 0.0, 4.7958317, 5.477226, 5.196152], Cluster M=[5.196152, 4.8989797, 9.486833, 6.928203, 4.8989797, 3.8729835, 7.071068, 7.071068, 3.1622777, 4.2426405, 5.477226, 6.708204, 0.0, 1.0], Cluster D=[7.1414285, 7.071068, 3.1622777, 0.0, 9.273619, 6.8556547, 2.828427, 4.690416, 6.78233, 10.198039, 6.3245554, 4.7958317, 6.928203, 6.5574384]}
**

Comment: printed the values a formatted value not exactly tabular but more readable form